# Preventing DLL hijacking vulnerability does not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport

Because I'd like to create a self-extracting format file(*.exe),
so I followed the instructions at the following URL:

[Secure loading of libraries to prevent DLL preloading attacks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2389418/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks)

In order to prevent DLL hijacking vulnerability, I tried to invalidate the current working directory (CWD) with `SetDllDirectory()`, like this:

```cs
namespace DllPreload
{
  static class Program
  {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Here is the main entry point of the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

      SetDllDirectory("");

      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}
```

However, placing vulnerable DLLs, such as `DWMAPI.DLL`, `DWrite.dll`, etc in the CWD, the DLLs will be loaded unintentionally before the entry point `Main()` can call `SetDllDirectory()`.

The other file names reproduced in Windows 10 (64 bit) are as follows.

- WTSAPI32.DLL
- PROPSYS.DLL
- MSIMG32.DLL
- INDOWSCODECS.DLL
- WINSTA.dll

I put the verification code in GitHub:

https://github.com/hibara/DllPreload

`DWMAPI.DLL` and `DWrite.dll` in the `Debug`, `Release` directory in the demo code are DLLs that have configured DLL preloading. The source code of the verification DLL is as follows:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) 
{
  MessageBox(NULL,
      "This program is vulnerable to DLL Hijacking.",
      "DLL Hijacked",
       MB_OK);
   return TRUE;
}
```

So my question is: What can be done in this case?

Comment: Usually we don't bother preventing DLL hijacking because, as Raymond Chen said, you're already on the other side of the airtight hatchway...

Comment: Actually, Not an installed application, I'd like to use it as a self-extracting file(exe), so I'd like to take measures it properly.

Comment: I'm also facing the same, could you please tell me how did you mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Preventing insecure loads only works for DLLs that are loaded **dynamically** using `LoadLibrary/Ex()`, so you control *where* they are loaded from. `DllImport` loads DLLs **statically**, which is why they load before `main()` runs, and you have no control over them.

See [Dynamically calling an unmanaged dll from .NET (C#)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/) for how to use `LoadLibrary/Ex()` in C#.

Comment: There no correlation between DllImports and "loaded before Main runs"... OP code shows problem because method had to be JITed before execution and hence needs implementations before method runs.…